# Strange Chrome Issue Table Border Top

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have spotted a strange issue with chrome when rendering table borders. I have four columns and I want the third column to have no borders. In Firefox it displays correctly, so that it looks like the first and second columns are a separate table from the fourth column, as you can see here:

[image]

However, in Chrome, the top border of the first columns extends right across all the other columns as you can see here:

[image]

This is what the html code is for this:

```
<tr style="border: none;">
    <td style="width: 120px;">Surname</td>
    <td style="width: 300px;">Bloggs</td>
    <td style="border: none; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="width: 100px;"><div class="studentimg" style="background-image:url('<%=strStudentPhoto%>');"></div></td>
</tr>
```

I know it is the first column that is cause the issue because I change the code to this:

```
<tr style="border: none;">
    <td style="width: 120px;">Surname</td>
    <td style="border-top: none; width: 300px;">Bloggs</td>
    <td style="border: none; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="border-top: none; width: 100px;"><div class="studentimg" style="background-image:url('<%=strStudentPhoto%>');"></div></td>
</tr>
```

and in Chrome it still shows as above, whereas in Firefox it now shows as only the first column have a top border, like this?

[image]

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this for Chrome?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

The following code (based on yours) does *not*  show the problem you described in Chrome.

Note: I removed a lot of the inline styles, i removed the inline border from the `tr`s, I applied `rowspan="3"` to the third cell in the first row and omitted the third cell in the following rows. For the rest of the settings see yourself in the snippet below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 120px;">Surname</td>
    <td style="width: 300px;">Bloggs</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="border: none; width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="width: 100px;">
      <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:url(https://placehold.it/67x100/fc5) center center no-repeat;background-size:contain;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Surname</td>
    <td>Bloggs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Surname</td>
    <td>Bloggs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Johannes. I amended my code to your match your suggestion, but it didn't work. I have had spent a few hours looking at my code and released it was something to with the row above the first one in my example. This is a title row, the code is this <td colspan="4" style="border: none;">Student Information</td>, if I reduce it  colspan="2", then it disappears. Don't know if this is a glitch with Chrome or Chrome and the Bootstrap framework I am using.